# How do I have my wxpython window stay open or re-open after I enter my text?

Tags: python, wxpython

Also, why does this not save to library.txt?  It does not close properly either (mac).  I wan't for this program to be able to run on windows OS primarily. Here is my spaghetti code:

http://pastebin.com/NLx77zHu

```
import wx
f = open('library.txt', "a")
class ooer(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(ooer, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(390, 125))
        box=wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "Dewey Number, Author Name", "Library", "ex. 822 SHA")
        if box.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
            answer=box.GetValue()
            f.write(answer)
f.close
if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.App()
    ooer(None, title='Add Books To Library')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code creates a frame that stays open until you close it by clicking the X.

It has seperate TextCtrl's for each line of entry and a button to click when you want to save.

It calls a seperate function to do the saving to file.

```
import wx
from wx.lib import sized_controls

class AddBooksFrame(sized_controls.SizedFrame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddBooksFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        pane = self.GetContentsPane()
        pane_form = sized_controls.SizedPanel(pane)
        pane_form.SetSizerType('form')
        pane_form.SetSizerProps(align='center')

        label = wx.StaticText(pane_form, label='Dewey Number')
        label.SetSizerProps(halign='right', valign='center')
        self.ctrl_dewey_no = wx.TextCtrl(pane_form, size=((200, -1)))

        label = wx.StaticText(pane_form, label='Author Name')
        label.SetSizerProps(halign='right', valign='center')
        self.ctrl_author_name = wx.TextCtrl(pane_form, size=((200, -1)))

        pane_btns = sized_controls.SizedPanel(pane)
        pane_btns.SetSizerType('horizontal')
        pane_btns.SetSizerProps(halign='right')

        btn_save = wx.Button(pane_btns, wx.ID_SAVE)
        btn_save.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_btn_save)
        self.Fit()

    def on_btn_save(self, event):
        dewey_no = self.ctrl_dewey_no.GetValue()
        author_name = self.ctrl_author_name.GetValue()
        try:
            add_book_to_file(dewey_no, author_name)
            self.ctrl_dewey_no.Clear()
            self.ctrl_author_name.Clear()
        except ValueError as exception:
            dialog = wx.MessageDialog(
                self, str(exception), 'Entry error',
                wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.OK | wx.CENTER)
            dialog.ShowModal()
            dialog.Destroy()


def add_book_to_file(dewey_no, author_name):
    if not dewey_no:
        raise ValueError('Dewey Number must not be empty')
    if not author_name:
        raise ValueError('Author Name must not be empty')

    with open('library.txt', "a") as library_txt:
        library_txt.write('{}, {}\n'.format(dewey_no, author_name))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wxapp = wx.App(False)
    main_app_frame = AddBooksFrame(
        None, title='Add Books To Library', style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)
    main_app_frame.Show()
    wxapp.MainLoop()
```

Comment: How do I add another box?  For the number of books I mean.